# Retrieve complete ID from partial id in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to retrieve the parent Id from the partial id when I click a button.

html sample:

```
<div class="test" id="my-id-123">
 <div class="etc">
   <button>button </button>
 <div>
<div>

<div class="test" id="my-id-456">
 <div class="etc">
   <button>button </button>
 <div>
<div>
```

so when I click the second button, can I retrieve the correct parent id using partial id 'my-id'?

I've tried the following approach, but it only gives me all the ids:

```
$('[id*="my-id"').closest('div')
```

Comment: Please show what attempts you made to solve this. Remember that SO is here to help you debug code, not to write code for you. With that said, research [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest)

Comment: Do you need id of first button on clicking second button ? What you meant by partial id ?

Comment: @melvin retrieve correct parent id. i.e. my-id-456

Comment: `$(this).closest('.test').prop('id')` where `this` is one of the buttons.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I've updated what I've tried. sorry for skipping that out earlier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `closest()` function of jQuery

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the
>   selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its
>   ancestors in the DOM tree.

If you need the id, on button click you can write the following inside the `onclick` function.

```
$(this).closest('.test').attr('id');
```

## UPDATE

Or you can use the one below using `.prop()` which is the best practice

```
$(this).closest('.test').prop('id');
```

Comment: is there a way of doing it without using this?

Comment: No. This is the best way when combined with a click event handler, although `attr()` should be `prop()`. Do you have an issue with it?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Sorry for my question. Is `prop()` necessary ?

Comment: You'll need either `attr()` or `prop()`, yes. The latter is better practice as it reads the property from the underlying Element object instead of accessing the DOM

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Ok. Thanks for the information. I will update

Answer (score 0):

If you must keep your HTML as is, put this into your event handler.

```
$(".etc > button").click(function(){
  var grandParent=$(this).parent().parent();
  console.log(grandParent[0].id);//Prints my-id-xxx
});
```

There is a fiddle just so you can verify: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5tnc3rov/)
It logs it to the javascript console, which should be accessible under F12.

EDIT: As Taplar pointed out, this is susceptible to any change in the DOM, and the `.closest()` method is better. Rewritten to reflect that, you get this.

```
$(".etc > button").click(function(){
    var grandParent=$(this).closest(".test");
  console.log(grandParent[0].id);
});
```

Comment: I already got the impression he was not keen on changing the markup given that he didn't make the buttons uniquely identifiable.